Reformulation of Hasse's Theorem for elliptic curves
This is exercise 4.13 from Elliptic Curves by Washington
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Show that Hasse's theorem can be restated as
$$\Big\vert \sqrt{\# E(\mathbb{F}_q)} - \sqrt{q}\Big\vert\leq1$$
Let $E:=\# E(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Starting with the expression above, for $E>q$, we get
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt E-\sqrt q&\leq 1\\
\Leftrightarrow E-q&\leq \sqrt E+\sqrt q\\
\Leftrightarrow E-q-1&\leq \sqrt E+\sqrt q-1\\
\Rightarrow E-q-1&\leq 2\sqrt q
\end{aligned}
For $E<q$ we get
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt q-\sqrt E&\leq 1\\
\Leftrightarrow q-E &\leq \sqrt q+\sqrt E\\
\Leftrightarrow q-E+1&\leq \sqrt q+\sqrt E+1\\
\Rightarrow q-E+1&\leq 2\sqrt q+1
\end{aligned}
Unfortunately I do not get better than this, I can't get rid of the $+1$. Also, I was not able to derive the other implication of inequalities
Starting with the Hasse bound I get for $E>q$
\begin{aligned}
E-q-1 &\leq 2\sqrt q \\
\Rightarrow \sqrt E\sqrt q-q-1&\leq 2\sqrt q\\
\Leftrightarrow \sqrt q(E-\sqrt q)&\leq 2\sqrt q+1\\
\Leftrightarrow \sqrt E-\sqrt q &\leq 2+\frac{1}{\sqrt q}
\end{aligned}
and for $q>E$
\begin{aligned}
q+1-E&\leq 2\sqrt q\\
\Rightarrow q+1-\sqrt E\sqrt q&\leq 2\sqrt q\\
\Leftrightarrow\sqrt q(\sqrt q-\sqrt E)+1&\leq 2\sqrt q\\
\Leftrightarrow\sqrt q - \sqrt E&\leq 2-\frac{1}{\sqrt q}
\end{aligned}
However, the boundaries I was able to derive here are worse than the one I am looking for. For every case I only make one estimation each, the rest are all equivalences, and I see no way how to improve these.
I would really appreciate any help on this problem! Is the inequality above really equivalent to Hasse's bound? Can anyone give me a hint how to prove this?

Let $E:=\# E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ as you did.
We want to prove that
$$|\sqrt E-\sqrt q|\le 1\tag1$$
is equivalent to
$$|E-q-1|\le 2\sqrt q\tag2$$
Jz Pan has already provided a good answer which proves that $(2)$ is equivalent to $(1)$.
On the other hand, you started with $(1)$ to prove that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$.
If you want to prove that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$, then note that we have $\sqrt E$ in $(1)$ while we have $E$ without $\sqrt E$ in $(2)$.
This should suggest that squaring $\sqrt E$ to get $E$ might work.
(You used the fact that $\sqrt E-\sqrt q=\frac{E-q}{\sqrt E+\sqrt q}$, but this produces another $\sqrt E$.)
Proof :
$$\begin{align}(1)&\iff -1\le \sqrt E-\sqrt q\le 1
\\\\&\iff \sqrt q-1\le\sqrt E\le \sqrt q+1
\\\\&\iff (\sqrt q-1)^2\le E\le (\sqrt q+1)^2
\\\\&\iff q-2\sqrt q+1\le E\le q+2\sqrt q+1
\\\\&\iff -2\sqrt q\le E-q-1\le 2\sqrt q
\\\\&\iff |E-q-1|\le 2\sqrt q.\ \ \blacksquare\end{align}$$

This is quite elementary:
let $n:=\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$, then the Hasse bound is (GTM106, Chapter V, Theorem 1.1)
$$
|n-q-1|\leq 2\sqrt{q},
$$
that is equivalent to say,
$$
(\sqrt{q}-1)^2=q+1-2\sqrt{q}\leq n\leq q+1+2\sqrt{q}=(\sqrt{q}+1)^2,
$$
taking square root, it's equivalent to
$$
\sqrt{q}-1\leq\sqrt{n}\leq\sqrt{q}+1,
$$
namely, $|\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{q}|\leq 1$.
